# float: right in inline css of td

Tags: html, css, html-table, right-align

My result and expectation in the image below:
[image]

for that I tried:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name:-</td>
    <td><strong>XYZ</strong></td>
    <span style="float: right;">
     <td>Age:-</td>
     <td><strong>38</strong></td>
   </span>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My result and expectation in the image below:
[image]

Comment: It looks like you're using tables wrong. you can put a `span` element inside the table cell but you can't wrap a table cell within a `span` as you did. it messes up the alignment of the table. Also, why are all the empty `<td></td>`? what's their purpose? You can read more about the HTML table [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) and [here](https://www.quackit.com/html/html_table_tutorial.cfm)

Comment: @Thatkookooguy empty columns were by mistake, How to make two columns at left and two columns at right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by using the default table layout mode and expanding the second table cell.

Because the table layout mode is set to [`auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout#Values), even if we expand one cell to the width of the table, the layout will expand that cell to take as much space as possible.

```css
table {
  width: 100%; /* <-- only this is necassery for this effect */
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.expand {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name:-</td>
    <td class="expand"><strong>XYZ</strong></td>
    <td>Age:-</td>
    <td><strong>38</strong></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The same effect can be achieved by adding an empty cell and expanding it:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name:-</td>
    <td><strong>XYZ</strong></td>
    <td class="expand"></td>
    <td>Age:-</td>
    <td><strong>38</strong></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there any class for the same in bootstrap 4?

Comment: @user10670473 most bootstrap classes contain more than one CSS attribute. you can use the `col-lg-12` to set `width: 100%` but it might set additional things you don't want in this case. If you really want to avoid using your own class, you can always use `style="width: 100%"` in the same way you applied the `float: right`